# Having trouble extracting values from JSON

Tags: java, json, parsing

Examples:

```
{"name":"tv.twitch:twitch:5.16"}

{"name":"tv.twitch:twitch-external-platform:4.5","extract":{"exclude":["META-INF/"]},"natives":{"windows":"natives-windows-${arch}"},"rules":[{"os":{"name":"windows"},"action":"allow"}]}
```

These lines came from a JSONArray, I'd like to extract the "natives" portion. The problem is, not all items in the JSONArray have the "natives" value. Here is my current code to extract the "name" value

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(readUrl(url.toString()));
JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("libraries");

ArrayList<String> libraries = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject next = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String lib = next.getString("name");
    libraries.add(lib);
}
```

I'm not exactly sure about this since I am new to java/JSON parsing, but would an object in the array without the "natives" value cause the program to end?

Comment: If you're using the `json.org` classes; `JSONObject` has a `has(String)` method, to determine if a key is present.

Comment: I need the "name", "natives", and in this case, "windows"

Comment: just use `try-catch` block when you'll get "natives" value.

Comment: It's unclear what object you have in the JSON above.  Is it the `next` JSON object from inside your loop?  If so then what you have should work.

Comment: qqilihq that may have been what i needed!

Comment: catching exceptions (constructing in fact) is quite costly operation, it is better to test existence than catch NullPointerException

Comment: @nikis - There's no need at all to use try-catch, except to handle malformed input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `has` method from JSONObject to determine if it contains specified key or not.

> Determine if the JSONObject contains a specific key.

In your case you can do like this:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(readUrl(url.toString()));
if(json.has("natives")) {
   //Logic to extract natives
} else {
   //Logic to extract without natives
}
```

I think this simple lines should suffice for your requirement. See the API:[here](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#has%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did after qqilihq mentioned about the "has" method

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to extract content at [JSON Pointer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901)s `/name` and `/extract/natives/windows`.

In this case, using [this library](https://github.com/fge/jackson-coreutils) (which depends on Jackson), it is as simple as:

```
// All of these are thread safe
private static final ObjectReader READER = JacksonUtils.getReader();
private static final JsonPointer NAME_POINTER = JsonPointer.of("name");
private static final JsonPointer WINDOWS_POINTER 
    = JsonPointer.of("extract", "native", "windows");

// Fetch content from URL
final JsonNode content = READER.readTree(url.getInputStream());
// Get content at pointers, if any
final JsonNode nameNode = NAME_POINTER.path(content);
final JsonNode windowsNode = WINDOWS_POINTER.path(content);
```

Then, to check if a node actually exists, check against `.isMissingNode()`:

```
if (windowsNode.isMissingNode())
    // deal with no windows content
```

Alternatively, use `.get()` instead of `.path()` and check for `null` instead.